# How to get hard drive serial number from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

From the Windows NT-based (Windows XP and 7 specifically) command prompt, how can I get the serial number of a hard drive as a variable? The one I'm looking at is the serial number of the physical hard disk drive

Comment: For Windows xp, see this question for a proper method: http://superuser.com/q/708146/24010

Comment: If you have many hard drives like me, use this instead to help you know which is which: `wmic diskdrive get name,size,model,SerialNumber`... [`Source`](http://whatsonmypc.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/wmic/)

Comment: Possibly related: [Getting HDD serial number](http://superuser.com/q/812294/354511).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[Try this command](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/vol-command.htm)

> vol C:

this will get the volume serial number given to it by windows.

> wmic diskdrive get serialnumber

this gets the manufacturers serial number of the hard drive.

Comment: I don't see that in his question, maybe he needs to re-word the title dude, "How to get hard drive serial number from command line?"

Comment: When using `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` I get the message `Invalid XML`. What does it mean?

Comment: I get invalid query error for `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber`.

Comment: @Maxbester and @atoMerz: I had both problems. `Invalid XML` was due to having more than one drive connected and `Invalid query` occurred because I was on Windows XP. See this answer for both issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287450/wmic-diskdrive-get-serialnumber-invalid-xml-output/23871382#answer-23871382

Comment: Caution!  `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` (and the `Win32_DiskDrive` WMI class in general) returns the serial number with each pair of characters reversed.  So if your hard drive label reads "abcd1234" WMI will report your serial number as "badc2143".  [More information here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297348/).

Comment: To help determine which serial belongs to which drive, use: `wmic diskdrive get Name,Model,SerialNumber`

Comment: for some reason the serial numbers in CMD dont match the serial numbers in SeaTools for Windows???

Comment: `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` is the output that im looking for, but it doesnt tell me which drive is which number?!

Comment: @oldboy Look in disk management to get the drive number related to each drive letter.

Comment: @Moab thanks i know i can get the `name`/`volumename` from `logicaldisk get`, but it would be nice if u could also get the `serialnumber` and `name`/`volumename` together

Comment: @oldboy Microsoft do something logical? Lol. Yeah it would be nice.

Comment: lol we can dream cant we?

Answer (score 8):

In the same vein as Moab's answer, but using PowerShell this time:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object Model,SerialNumber
```

This command gets an instance of the [`Win32_DiskDrive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class and outputs the model of each disk drive in the computer and its corresponding serial number from that instance.

This answer assumes PowerShell 3.0 or later. If running an older version, use [`Get-WmiObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject) in place of [`Get-CimInstance`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance).

On Windows 8 and later, you can also use this command:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object FriendlyName,SerialNumber
```

Comment: Doesn't work for NVMe drives.  I am guessing NVMe drives just don't expose their serial at all.  For NVMe drives, WMI reports a long number which in no way matches any part of the serial on the physical label.

Answer (score 6):

- What you are looking at is **NOT** the hard drive serial number.
- It is called the [Volume Serial Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_serial_number). It is generated at the time of creating and formatting the volume / partition.
- You can get it by using a command at command prompt : `C:\> vol c:` if `C:` is the drive you want to retrieve the Volume Serial Number for.
- All you can do is redirect the output of that command to a file : `C:\> vol c: > myvol.txt` and it will be stored as a text file in your `C:`
- I am attaching a screenshot with the highlights:

[image]

- The file was stored in the root of `C:`

[image]

- This is what the `myvol.txt` file looks like in Notepad:

[image]

Comment: Question edited; sorry for the mis-information

Comment: Before considering a down vote to this answer, please note that it was posted before the OP clarified the original question. This answer was indeed correct for the original question.

Comment: serial numbers retrieved this way do not match the serial numbers in SeaTools for Windows???

Answer (score 6):

In a batch file one approach is:

1. VOL command to produce the serial number as text along with text we don't want.
2. FIND to trim it down to only the line with the serial number.
3. FOR to grab the 5th token (a part between delimiters) on the line with the serial number.
4. SET to assign to an environment variable

---

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%a in ('vol c: ^| Find "Serial Number"') do (
set VOLSERIAL=%%a
)
```

Comment: Question edited; sorry for the mis-information

Comment: Before considering a down vote to this answer, please note that it was posted before the OP clarified the original question. This answer was indeed correct for the original question.

Comment: I used this method to easily identify hard disks and drive letter mappings in a cmd batch file. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Get the "windows serial number" from powershell:

```
(-split (cmd /c vol c: | select-string serial))[4]

G92B-EC00
```

Alternatively,

```
get-ciminstance Win32_LogicalDisk | % VolumeSerialNumber

G92BEC00
```

Comment: That’s cool and all (there’s probably a more PS-y way), but: “The one I'm looking at is the serial number of the physical hard disk drive”