# Getting HDD serial number

Tags: hard-drive, wmic, serial-number

I'm trying to get the serial number of the hard disks in my PC, i.e. the number printed on a label on the hard disk itself. I found that I can do that using `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber`, but I see that the serial number returned has the string "202020202020202020202020" before another 16 characters. I've never seen this long "202020..." string before a hard disk's serial number before. Is this correct?

ETA: The full string is "2020202020202020202020205139334d47585052".

Comment: Paste the entire string. Most likely, it's hexadecimal ASCII and the 20's are padding.

Comment: I just added the whole string in my original post.

Comment: It's hexadecimal ASCII and the 20's are padding. For example, the `585052` at the end is `XPR`.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to get the Hard Drive serial number](http://superuser.com/q/708146/354511) and [How to get hard drive serial number from command line?](http://superuser.com/q/498083/354511)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz where can I find more information on how the serial string is formed there? as you mentioned above the last 6 digits are XPR what about the rest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get hard drive serial number from command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/498083/how-to-get-hard-drive-serial-number-from-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip that Windows utility and load smartctl

Then open an admin command line in the "c:\program files\smartmontools\bin" folder and type:

```
smartctl -i /dev/sda
```

*Or sdb sdc etc depending on the drive location

This will show the serial number in a clean easy to read format... and the drive health.

You will find the utility here:

### http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/files/smartmontools/6.3/

Answer (score 2):

Windows **Powershell** will give you clean human readable output:

```
get-wmiobject win32_physicalmedia | select-object Tag, SerialNumber
```

It outputs something like this:

```
| Tag                | SerialNumber |
|--------------------|--------------|
| \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 | 5VK04NR1     |
| \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 | 5VK07RG1     |
| \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 | 5VK07QEM     |
```