# how to get primary harddisk serial number only

Tags: windows, command-line

I run below command in cmd in Windows:

```
wmic diskdrive get serialnumber
```

which gives me the following result:

```
SerialNumber
W2B0MMLM
S2SMJ9DD906854
```

What if I only want primary harddisk's serial number only?

Comment: You pipe the result into something like [Select-Object](https://superuser.com/questions/498083/how-to-get-hard-drive-serial-number-from-command-line) where you then "select" the HDD you are interested in.  You can also use the [where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287450/wmic-diskdrive-get-serialnumber-invalid-xml-output) clause based on the ID of the HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound I am currently developing an application which will run on some other computer(s). I want to collect the primary harddisk serial number from that computer. So, how can I use ID in that case?

Comment: You have to determine which is the first physical disk, I might have read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287450/wmic-diskdrive-get-serialnumber-invalid-xml-output) incorrectly, but I sort of assumed it was going to match `PHYSICALDRIVE0` or something similar.  However, would like to point out by advice is still sound, pipe or where clause would be what you would need to use.

Comment: @Ramhound I got the result by using this command: `wmic path win32_physicalmedia where tag='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' get serialnumber /format:list` Now I want to remove the word SerialNumber from output. Is it possible to specify in commmand?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
wmic logicaldisk where (DeviceID="C:") assoc /assocclass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
```

With this command you get the partition id ("Disk #0, Partition #0"). (If you have the system installed on C drive. You can change the letter anytime)

```
wmic partition where (DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #0") assoc /assocclass:Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition
```

With this command you get the physical drive id ("\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0")

```
wmic path win32_diskdrive where deviceid='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0' get serialnumber
```

With this you get the serial number of the primary hard disk.